# meaning of $k(C)/1+\mathfrak{m}_x$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over some field $k$ and $x$ a closed point of $C$. I've seen some constructions in which people use

$k(C)^\times / 1+\mathfrak{m}_x$.

What's the meaning of that? I know that here $k(C)$ is the function field of the curve and I guess that $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{C, x}$. So what does it mean that two regular functions on the curve have the same class modulo $1+\mathfrak{m}_x$?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are exact sequences
$$1\rightarrow  \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^*\rightarrow k(C)^*\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$
(order of a function at $x$), and
$$1\rightarrow 1+\mathfrak{m}_x \rightarrow  \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^* \rightarrow \kappa(x)^*\rightarrow 1$$
(evaluation at $x$). Thus $(k(C)^* / 1+\mathfrak{m}_x)$ is an extension 
$$1\rightarrow \kappa(x)^* {\buildrel {i}\over {\longrightarrow}}\ (k(C)^* / 1+\mathfrak{m}_x ){\buildrel {v}\over {\longrightarrow}}\ \Bbb{Z}\rightarrow 0\ .$$
  I don't think there is much more to say...